# Getting data directly from Google docs error in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-docs

I am trying to load a spreadsheet formatted in CSV directly from Google Docs.
I've published it and get this URL, which works great in a browser,
and if I run withing the Flash CS5 IDE.
When it's running in a web-browser (locally or online), it just hangs and never loads or give an error.

> var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest(file);        var
>   loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
>   loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadXML);
>   loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onLoadXMLError); 
>   loader.load(request);

Any thoughts?

http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AhTK6MB0cCLQdDloTFd0TDgzVE04Nm51RTMtM3I3WUE&hl=en&output=csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load across domains like that. It's a potential security issue.

You have a few options:

- Have google add a [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html) that allows your domain to do this. (not likely)
- Use another host for your CSV (easier, but I'm guessing you want the editing from docs)
- Use a [proxy script](http://xmlrpcflash.mattism.com/proxy_info.php) on a server of yours that loads the file for you (likely the best option)